# create a new column with the file name in R

Tags: r

I do web scraping of a table, but I would like to add a new column with the name of that file in all rows (like a ID in each row) containing information. Example:

the file name is "16-12-19.xlsx"

so I wanted to add a new column with "16-12-19" written on each line that contains an information.

Example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Ma4.png)

*the data format I customize later

the whole code is:

```
library("openxlsx")
library('rvest')

start <- as.Date("16-12-19",format="%d-%m-%y")
end   <- as.Date("05-01-20",format="%d-%m-%y")
theDate <- start

while (theDate <= end)
{
  url <- (paste0("http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/produtos-e-servicos/emprestimo-de-ativos/renda-variavel/emprestimos-registrados/renda-variavel-8AE490CA64CD50310164D1EFD6412F1C.htm?data=",format(theDate,"%d/%m/%y"),"&f=0"))
  site <- read_html(url)
  Info_Ajuste_HTML <- html_nodes(site,'table')


  Info_ajuste <- html_text(Info_Ajuste_HTML)
  head(Info_ajuste,20)
  if (length(Info_Ajuste_HTML) > 0) { ### <- Added a check here
  head(Info_Ajuste_HTML)

  lista_tabela <- site %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE) 
  str(lista_tabela)
  head(lista_tabela[[1]], 10)
  AJUSTE <- lista_tabela[[1]]
  #View(AJUSTE)
  write.xlsx(AJUSTE, file=paste0("C:/Users/Jessé/Desktop/R/XLS/",paste0(format(theDate,"%d-%m-%y"),".xlsx")), col.names = (FALSE)) 
  theDate <- theDate + 1 
  }

  else {theDate <- theDate + 1 }

  }
```

Comment: `fl <- sub("\\.xlsx$", "", "16-12-19.xlsx"); df$filename <- as.Date(fl, format = "%d-%m-%y")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df[,c(filename)] = rep(filename, nrow(df))` where `df` is the data frame containing the data from this file and `filename` contains the name of the file.

Comment: I edited my question and put the entire code to make it easier. your code generated an error in" filename"

Comment: Without viewing the actual HTML data, I am assuming `AJUSTE` is the data frame containing the table data.  If so, use `AJUSTE` in place of `df` in the solution code snippet.